sklearn OneHotEncoder - create new dataframe with certain rows that have value = 1
I have a dataframe with 20 columns and 10000 rows. I applied OneHotEncoder (drop='first') to the entire dataframe which gave me 79 columns. I am trying to grab specific rows and create a new dataframe from these new rows by doing:
df_new = df[df['column'] == 1.0] 

(since OneHotEncoder outputs 1.0's and 0.0's), but it throws an error. Is there a way to grab the row if a specific 'column' equals 1.0?

KeyError: "None of [Index([0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,\n       ...\n       0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0],\n      dtype='float64', length=8124)] are in the [columns]"


Can you share more of what you have done before the line of code you shared? That way should slice the dataframe in the way you expect it to. The error seems to imply that you've sliced over the columns instead of rows with the criteria

always put FULL error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information in the full error/traceback. It will be also more readable in question, and more people can see it - so more people may help.

error suggests that it search value or column with string (literally) "None of ...are in the [columns]". But you didn't show full error message so maybe you have problem in different line of code.

Maybe first use print() (and print(type(...)), print(len(...)), etc.) to see which part of code is executed and what you really have in variables. It is called "print debugging" and it helps to see what code is really doing.
